# "Cannot load resource" in Visual Studio 2015 toolbar with a DSL

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, toolbox, dsl-tools

Since converting a DSL-tools language to Visual Studio 2015, the toolbox options are gone, there are no options to add model elements to the DSL editor.

If I select the "Show All" option in the Visual Studio 2015 toolbox I see a strange "Cannot load resource" entry that I'm assuming that corresponds to the toolbox tab of my DSL.

[image: Visual Studio Toolbox]

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening here or any tips on how to diagnose how Visual Studio 2015 loads the toolbox so that I can find which is the "resource" that it cannot load?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution a little by chance. This post pointed me in the right direction:

[DSL designers built from migrated beta 2 solutions might have empty toolbox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmprieur/archive/2010/02/17/dsl-designers-built-from-migrated-beta-2-solutions-might-have-empty-toolbox.aspx)

The setting missing in the DSL package csproj file was the following:

```
<RegisterWithCodebase>true</RegisterWithCodebase>
```

It got lost in the transition from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2015 while editing the projects references.